# Python function that takes value from a dict and return full dictionary for the value

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to write a function that takes a value for a given key (User_ID) and return the full dictionary for that value. I understand that this can probably be achieved without writing a function but as a beginner I'm trying to build my knowledge with functions.

My data is a list of dictionaries and looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "User_ID":"Z000",
      "DOB":"01.01.1960",
      "State":"Oregon",
      "Bought":["P1","P2"]
   },
   {
      "User_ID":"A999",
      "DOB":"01.01.1980",
      "State":"Texas",
      "Bought":["P5","P9"]
   }
]
```

I wrote the following function but I realized that this is would only work for a dictionary but I have a list of dictionaries. How can I make it to take the `User_ID` value and return the full dictionary including the `User_ID`, `DOB`, `State` and `Bought`.

```
def find_user(val):
    for key, value in dict_1.items():
         if val == key:
             return value
 
    return "user not found"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to iterate over the list and compare the `UserID` of a dictionary with an input UserID:

```
def find_user(val, lsts):
    for d in lsts:
        if val == d['User_ID']:
            return d
    return "user not found"
```

Then

```
print(find_user('Z000', lsts))
```

prints

```
{'User_ID': 'Z000',
 'DOB': '01.01.1960',
 'State': 'Oregon',
 'Bought': ['P1', 'P2']}
```

and

```
print(find_user('000', lsts))
```

prints

```
user not found
```

If however, your data is like:

```
d = { "Data": [{"User_ID":"Z000"},{"User_ID":"A999"} ]}
```

Then you can pass the list inside the dictionary to the function like:

```
find_user('Z000', d['Data'])
```

which returns

```
{'User_ID': 'Z000'}
```

Comment: If my data above was enclosed into its own dictionary such as `{ "Data": [{"User_ID":"Z000"},{"User_ID":"A999"} ]}`, how this would alter your answer to access the nested dictionaries?

Comment: The same result, the full dictionary for a specific user.

Comment: I want only `{"User_ID":"Z000"}`

Comment: Have been wrapping my head around and now I found the issue. Even though the data reads as `{ "Data": [{"User_ID":"Z000"},{"User_ID":"A999"} ]}`, it's actually a list as it's json. What change to the function is needed to account for this?

Comment: @elideli then you can use `import json` `json.loads(your_data)` and then use the function

Comment: Makes sense, thanks you so much, you are a gem!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to write a function for this task, your design is on the right track, but needs to be modified to account for the fact that you have a list of dictionaries.  Something like this might work:

```
def find_user(userid):
    for user_dict in big_list_of_user_dictionaries:
        if user_dict['User_ID'] == userid:
            return user_dict
```

However, you might be better off creating a new dictionary, where each key is the userid, and each value is one of your user info dictionaries.  You could use Python's dictionary comprehensions to make such a dictionary quickly:

```
 user_dict = {d['User_ID'] : d for d in big_list_of_user_dictionaries}
```

Then you could find the user info dictionary for any user by looking up their id in the `user_dict`, like this:

```
 print(user_dict['Z000'])
```

Comment: Love the dictionary comprehension method but how do you handle invalid User_ID values other than letting Python throw a `KeyError` ?

Comment: You can use the `get` function to get a value from a dictionary without risking a `KeyError`.  For example, `user_dict.get('X123')` would return `None` if the key is not found.  You can also give `get` a second argument which is the default value to use if the key is not found, for example `user_dict.get('X123', 'Not Found')`.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code works for you.

```
 def find_user(val):
       for dict_key in l:
          if dict_key["User_ID"] == val:
             return dict_key
       else:
          return "User Not Found"
    
    print(find_user("Z000"))
```

here l is the list that stores all your dictionaries.